# What is an easy way to copy multiple specific files from one folder to another?

Tags: macos

I have a folder that contains 2000 photos. I have a list of photo file names, about 350 that i like to move from one folder to another rather then selecting them individually or going through line by line and selecting. Is there a easier way i can do it.

I can have the 350 file names in .txt if needed.

Copy selective 350 photo files from Directory A (2000 photofiles) to Directory B.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming no space characters etc in the filenames you can use Terminal to run

```
cd "/path/to/A"
cp -- $(< "/path/to/list_of_files") "/path/to/B/"
```

If there are space characters in the filenames, or if the command above fails because there are too many files, use

```
cd "/path/to/A"
while IFS= read -r f; do
  cp -- "$f" "/path/to/B/"
done < "/path/to/list_of_files"
```

PS: If you want to move the files, use `mv` instead of `cp`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure each file name is on its own line in the text file.

Then in Terminal, do this:

```
cd /path/to/photo/files
cat list_of_files.txt | while read FILE; do
  mv "$FILE" /path/where/you/want/them
done
```

Comment: Needless use of `cat ... |` as `< files.txt` can be place either in front of `while` or after `done` to read the `files.txt`. Also, the `-r` _option_ should be used with the `read` _command_, and the destination _path_ in the `mv` _command_ should be shown quoted as a proper example in case the actual _path_ has spaces (as well as the `cd` _command_).

Comment: All the points @user3439894 made are valid.  I do use this syntax a lot, with never an issue.  But then, I NEVER put spaces in file names or directory names.  I added the quote marks in case any of OP's file names had spaces, and I should have done it on the paths for the same reason.

Comment: Spaces in file and folder names are incredibly common on macOS. Even system files contain them. It's rarely safe to assume their absence. *It's a valid character* in paths.

Comment: I said _I_ never create them, because after thirty-plus years in software, I am well aware that there still exist apps made by coders who fail to consider that a file name might contain other than alphanumeric.  Nothing I can do about Apple pretending those coders don’t exist.  Fortunately, system files rarely need me to mess with them.